# in mysql, set permission to connect mysql command line

Tags: mysql

creating users through mysql admin, but unable to login `mysql` command line

following on-line suggestions, as root issued

```
grant all on *.* to new_user;
```

it worked, but security-wise was a mess, so issued

```
revoke all on *.* from new_user;
```

now `new_user` can *still* connect, but security is sane as set in mysql admin

to me this is thoroughly hocus-pocus.  what's really going on, and how do you really enable login?

this seems to be a MySQL Administrator problem (thanks @marco).  if the same GRANT is issued in mysql command line, the user *can* log in; but it the grant is issued in Administrator, the user *cannot* log in.

as @marco pointed out, *any* access will grant mysql login access to the user, eg, SELECT privileges - *but* they need to be entered in msql command line.

Comment: Try on serverfault.com. And you did not provide basic information on how to establish the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you first use `GRANT`, user is created automatically; when you revoke privileges, user remains...
Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

First you should give your user only the privileges he really needs.
Second: give the user access only to db or tables he should see/work on.
Example:

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON mydb.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

or

```
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost' 
IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'sdsd';
```

**EDITED:**
Just to prove what I'm saying:
enter mysql console (`mysql -u root -p`) and type

```
USE mysql;
SELECT * FROM user;
```

You'll see users MySql has inside.
Well, now use `GRANT` as you please on a user which does not exists yet; then repeat `SELECT * FROM user;`: you'll see new user created!!

Comment: thought user was created in MySQL Administrator.  certainly the privs set there took correctly.

Comment: also thought `create user` was used to create a user

Comment: @cc young: yes, you can create user using `CREATE USER`; anyway when you use `GRANT` if user exists privileges are assigned to him, otherwise user is created and permissions assigned. Try to guess :)

Comment: thanks for that clarification. but what about `grant all on *.*` made it where the user could login?  for example, tried `grant usage on *.*`, but would not allow the user to login.

Comment: @cc_young: read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html) and [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html). From one of these:  The USAGE privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used at the global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource limits or SSL characteristics without affecting existing account privileges.

Comment: just tested myself: created user - no login.  granted user SELECT on a table - can login.  what permissions does SELECT carry with it to allow login?  second, when those same permissions are given via MySQL Administrator, cannot log in.  I'm seeing the results, but have no real understanding.

Comment: @cc_young: I cannot explain what books and authors do in hundreds pages. Read carefully links I provided. A user can login to a database if he has some privilege on it (for example SELECT, i.e. readonly), otherwise access is denied

Comment: Everything you said is correct and I appreciate your taking time on this.  "A user can login to a database if he has some privilege on it" - the problem is that if the privileges are set through MySQL Administrator the user _cannot_ login.  Maybe the answer is not to use it!